# How can I change the color of the selected spinner item using XML not Java?

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-spinner

I have an Android `Spinner` and the dropdown colors are all working ok but I can't change the text color of the selected item using XML, not Java. I've tried everything I could think of. Below is my code:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/test"
        style="@style/dropdown_text"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"></android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner>
```

Here are all the things I've tried with style:

```
<style name="dropdown_text">
    <item name="android:background">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/white_text</item>
</style>

<style name="white_text">
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
</style>
```

The background color works just fine but not the text color.

So how can I change the selected item text color?

Thanks.

Edit: I know there are tons of posts asking this same thing, the majority of them say to do it in Java code but I want to do it on XML. Also some show the styles you have to change but I've tried all their suggestions and nothing has worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you populate your `Spinner` with `entries`, [`AppCompatSpinner` will create an `ArrayAdapter`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatSpinner.java#L268-L274) and use [`android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/simple_spinner_item.xml) as your "selected" view. `simple_spinner_item` is a `TextView` styled using `spinnerItemStyle`.

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:textAlignment="inherit"/>
```

So, if you want to change the text color in `simple_spinner_item`, you'll need to supply your own style for `spinnerItemStyle`. Something like:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/YourSpinnerItemStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="YourSpinnerItemStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.TextView.SpinnerItem">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

You could also use `textAppearance` instead of `textColor`.

Results:

[image]

Comment: Your answer appears correct, but for some reason on my actual code, `android:textColorPrimary` from my main app theme ends up overriding the text color no matter what I do. But on the sample I posted above I can not get it to break.

Comment: It appears to only be an issue inside a dialog. I'm going to mark your answer as correct since it is correct for what I originally posted. Once I can reproduce it on a simple sample I'll have to create a new post.

Comment: Oh wow I made a huge mistake. My sample had the right `TextView` when creating the adapter but my actual code was just using the default one. I'll apply the bounty as soon as stackoverflow lets me.

Answer (score 0):

```
<item android:state_activated="true" 
android:drawable="@color/red"/>
```

Try this to set a color for a selected item

Answer (score -1):

You can use this code

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            TextView selectedText = (TextView)adapterView.getChildAt(0); 
            if (selectedText != null) {
                selectedText.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks but like I said, I know you can do it in Java but I want to do it in XML. Is it not possible?